# Replacing multiple occurences of special characters by a single special character

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove multiple occurrences of special characters like `" "`, `"-"`, `"!"`, `"_"` from my java string by a single underscore `"_"`. 
I tried

```
replaceAll("([\\s\\-\\!])\\1+","_")
```

and it seems to replace consecutive same type of special character by a underscore but doesn't work otherwise.
for eg:

```
Hello!!!  World
```

becomes

```
Hello__World
```

(2 underscores.)But It should be `Hello_World`.

Also for cases like `Hello - World` it fails.
I also tried working with regex and made a regular expression like

```
replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z0-9])\\1+","_")
```

but it still doesn't help. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Just use `[\\s!-]+` pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `\1` is a backreference to the *contents* matched with the first capturing group. To actually match one or more any characters from the character class, just use a `+` quantifier:

```
[\\s!-]+
```

So, use

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\s!-]+","_");
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/gZBVo8)

Comment: correct so when I added 1 it was matching to the first group right!! Thanks I was able to do it

Comment: Yes, you can read more about [backreferences here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).