# Java RegEx - How to prevent that a row of special characters is replaced by just one other character?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

What I want to do with the Regular Expression (Regex) is basically the [opposite to this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992261/replacing-multiple-occurences-of-special-characters-in-java-by-a-single-special).

I currently use this pattern for creating URL compatible file names:

```
String new_file_name = old_file_name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9._]+", "_");
```

If have for example example

````
String old_file_name = "!§$%&{}[]()=´´```_lol_á_^_°.PNG";
````

then new_file_name will be the following with the above pattern: `__lol______.PNG`

**However**, I want to have it differently. This regex pattern removes whole consecutive rows of special characters by just one underscore but I want that the pattern to replace EVERY SINGLE OCCURRENCE of a special character with its own underscore which would give me this result instead:

```
__________________lol______.PNG
```

Is there a way to achieve this with regex?

**Post-answer Edit:**
 Thank you guys for your fantastic answers! Really helped me a lot!
For completeness sake I want to provide you my clunky and awkward code snippet with which I achieved the same result like the regular expression you stated:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < old_file_name.length(); i++)
    {
        // if it is a letter, a number, a underscore or a dot
        if(     (((int)old_file_name.charAt(i) > 47)  &&  ((int)old_file_name.charAt(i) < 58 )) ||
                (((int)old_file_name.charAt(i) > 64)  &&  ((int)old_file_name.charAt(i) < 91 )) ||
                (((int)old_file_name.charAt(i) > 96)  &&  ((int)old_file_name.charAt(i) < 123 )) ||
                ((int)old_file_name.charAt(i) == 95) ||
                ((int)old_file_name.charAt(i) == 46)  )
        {

            // do nothing
        } // end if
        else
        {
            new_file_name = new_file_name.replace(old_file_name.charAt(i), '_');

            // System.out.println("Step " + i + " : " + new_file_name); // for debugging
        } // end if-else
     } // end for
```

Comment: newmsg = message.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z0-9._])+", "_");

Comment: Do you know what `+` represents in regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove the + in the end `[^a-zA-Z0-9._]` so you can use :

```
String new_file_name = old_file_name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9._]", "_");
//-------------------------------------------------------------^
```

**Output**

```
__________________lol______.PNG
```

because `+` mean **Match one or more times.** but in your case you need to replace all them so you don't need the `+`.

Answer (score 2):

The '+' at the end of your regex is saying "get all of these characters in a row together and replace all of them with this second string." You want to remove the "+", and it should work fine. You're already using "String.replaceAll()", which will repeat the replacement as many times as possible throughout the input string.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove "+". This will solve problem.

https://regex101.com/r/Lxbc3z/2